# PHP associate form fields with other fields

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that will be used for quoting items.  The user will be able to add blocks of fields to the form which I have working at the moment.  Consider the code below

```
<div class="fields">
   <select name="landscaping[]">
      <option value="1">Rocks</option>
      <option value="2">Other Rocks</option>
   </select>

   <select name="veneer[]">
      <option value="1">Veneer Rocks</option>
      <option value="2">Other Veneer Rocks</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="quantity[]">

</div>
```

The problem is the user may select either veneer or landscaping but not both but no matter what there will be a quantity associated with the choice.  And likely an additional parameter.  I need a way to associate quantity with veneer or landscaping in each instance of this section.

Comment: So are both form select fields showing at the same time, or do you have javascript hiding one?

Comment: Yes javascript hides one

Comment: are you using any javascript libraries, like jQuery? If so I can expand my answer further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using javascript to hide one of the elements at a time, I would also include a hidden field which holds the value of the select field which you want to grab the value from.  You could also just look for the one which has a value, but since they can probably each have a value, it's safer to send a value which tells you for sure which field you should pull from.

```
<div class="fields">
   <select name="landscaping[]">
      <option value="1">Rocks</option>
      <option value="2">Other Rocks</option>
   </select>

   <select name="veneer[]">
      <option value="1">Veneer Rocks</option>
      <option value="2">Other Veneer Rocks</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="quantity[]">

   <!-- This value should change depending on which one is currently visible -->
   <input type="hidden" name="selectedField" value="landscaping">

</div>
```

Then in your form processing page use something like the following:

```
$selection = $_POST[$_POST['selectedField']];
```

This will pull the value of your `selectedField` post dynamically and use it to then grab the correct select list. Using this method can be risky though... **Make sure that you sanitize your POST data!**

Comment: It will work, but the more fields I add, the more complex it gets.  I'm gonna see if I can take what you've given me and add to it. Thanks.

Comment: So, you're saying that there could be multiple fields that can be created on the fly?  I will modify my answer to address this.

Comment: @user1815207  How about the updated code? This should allow you to pull the correct field no matter how many are added.

Comment: I don't exactly how your answer addresses the problem at this point. How is the second post call supposed to work? I also don't see how it fixes the problem of needing to associate the fields that are generated on the fly.  I'm kinda heading in a different direction with the fields named items[0][veneer] and so on which will give me an associative array that I can loop through more easily. The only problem is changing the items index is now a thorn in my side.  If your solution is simpler and I just don't understand it, perhaps a little more explaining would help me to see it.

Comment: Could you maybe post more of your code, including the javascript and php? It's hard to get a good feel of what you're going for...